# Difference between apt-get and dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

What is the difference between these two? 
Also why if I do `apt-get purge XY` I still see XY when I invoke `dpkg -l` ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-get` handles lists of packages available to the system. It also handles package dependecy resolution, so that when installing a package, all the other packages required by it get installed too. It also handles package download from package repositories.

`dpkg` is the low level tool that actually installs package contents to the system.

If you try to install a package with `dpkg` whose dependencies are missing, dpkg will exit and complain about missing dependencies.

With apt-get it also installs the dependencies.

Comment: So apt-get wraps dpkg? The list of installed packages is then central in the system?

Comment: Yes, `apt-get` uses `dpkg` for the actual package installation.